# JAX-RS webapp deployed to Tomcat returns HTTP 404 error while it works fine in Eclipse

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs, http-status-code-404

i'm trying o deploy a Jax-RS webapp on Tomcat using Apache CXF implementation. Its a simple webapp for an exercise for university. When i do it using Eclipse all works fine, the applicaion gets recognized and i can reach it using web browser. If i try to generate a war and deploy it in any other way, it gets recognized but i can't reach it in any way, what am i missing?

[service implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUjCf.png)

[service interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nYnh.png),
[application class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39FOc.png)
my directory structure in webapps directory is:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocQsC.png)

i try to reach the webapp at "localhost:8080/es4.3/eshop/items"
but i get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JICc.png)

im using old versions of Tomcat because that's what's our teacher told us, because of some incompatibility between Apache CXF and jax-ws due to its tranisition to jakarta

Comment: There could be several reasons for that. You didnt write how you build/deploy your app to tomcat, so first might be different context root. Second you didnt show "imports" in your classes do you have javax. or jakarta. imports?, you wrote that you use old tomcat (but which version?) maybe it doesnt support jakarta imports.

Comment: As I said, the same exact app (I just copy/paste code to eclipse) works fine when I deploy it with eclipse instead of just copying the war file, so I don't think the problem is a compatibility problem. Anyway (sorry for the lack of info, is my first post) I'm using Tomcat 9.0.70, CXF 3.5.5, which where suggested by my professor to avoid incompatibility issues, and I'm using javax

Comment: Try to rename your war to lowercase es4.3.war and then use lowercase in Url when accessing the app.

Comment: Nothing changed. Anyway, the version deployed through Eclipse responded even with uppercase text.